# How to enter/validate sudo password without re-prompt?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo

For the purposes of a bash script I need to prompt the user for the `sudo` password if it hasn't been entered yet (and if the user doesn't have `sudo` privileges at the time they run the script).

I first request the password with `dialog` password bog, and then feed it to `sudo`, like so:

```
SUDOPWD=$(dialog --title "Password" --clear --passwordbox "Enter your sudo password" 10 30  2>&1 > /dev/tty)

echo ${SUDOPWD} | sudo -Sn -v
```

But, alas, that does not work! Apparently `-S` (read password from `stdin`), and `-n` (non-interactive `sudo`) are not compatible! With `-n` present, the password being fed to `sudo` is ignored (and so no elevation occurs), and without it `sudo` prompts for re-entry if an incorrect password was entered.

Is there any way to validate `sudo` password without re-prompting for it if it's not the right one?

Inevitably someone will point out that one should not be re-inventing the wheel, and just use `sudo`'s provided facility, or that feeding a password to `sudo` via a pipe has security implications. I'm aware of those factors, and still would like to do what I'm outlining above is it is possible. I also don't want to enter the commands in `/etc/sudoers`, recompile `sudo` (as the script should be somewhat portable), or disable `sudo` password prompt in general (just in this script).

I'm working on this on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I suppose I can leave the `-n` switch out, and redirect all output to null.. `echo ${SUDOPWD} | sudo -S -v &> /dev/null`. It seems to work (if `sudo` prompt occurs, it doesn't seem to be holding things up). It's kind of a kludge, though.. any cleaner solutions?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/515292/how-to-get-gui-sudo-password-prompt-without-command-line

Answer (score 4):

You can determine if the user is already authenticated with `sudo -vn 2>/dev/null`

If they're not, you can use the following to ask for a password and pipe it into `sudo`.

```
printf '%s\n' "$(dialog --output-fd 1 --passwordbox "Enter password:" 10 30)" | \
sudo -Svp ''
```

- `--output-fd 1` tells `dialog` to output to `STDOUT`
- `printf` is used to append a newline to the input, which is required for `sudo -S`
- `sudo -p ''` uses `''` as the password prompt message, hiding it

If you're cool with storing your output in a variable, you can just `printf '%s\n' "${SUDOPWD}"` and that should do it